# Question about the relationship between resistive drag, dissipated power, and velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, energy, work, power

This is from a high school physics exam for 16 year olds that I did two years ago. I still don't understand it.

> The power $P$ required to move an object through a medium at constant speed depends on the speed $v$ and the resistive force $F$ acting on the object.
>
> The resistive force $F$ also depends on the speed $v$.
>
> Which row shows a possible relationship between speed $v$, resistive force $F$ and power $P$?
>
> $$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
> & \text{resistive force }F & \text{power }P \\ \hline
> \mathrm{(a)} & \text{proportional to }v & \text{constant} \\
> \mathrm{(b)} & \text{proportional to }v & \text{proportional to }v \\
> \mathrm{(c)} & \text{proportional to }v^2 & \text{proportional to }v^2 \\
> \mathrm{(d)} & \text{proportional to }v^2 & \text{proportional to }v^3 
> \end{array}$$

I look at it like this: $P=F \cdot v$ and $F=kv$. Then I can say that the resistive force $F$ is proportional to $v$, and I can say that the power is $k\cdot v \cdot v$. Then $P$ is proportional to $v^2$.

And evidently this answer is not available. So I am wrong. Have no idea why though. Would  someone please give me a little lesson. The answer is (d).

Edit: good answers from the both of you. I see that such a question can only be answered by noticing that the difference in indices varies by +1. Because there is no option for the answer I got, I suppose it leaves answer d as the only option. (Somebody correct me if I am wrong please)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is not asking for *the* relationship between force, power and velocity - there are multiple possible ways for drag to increase with velocity, depending on the regime you're in, so there is no unique answer.

Instead, the question is asking you to identify which of the given combinations of force and power scalings is internally consistent, and nothing more - hence the wording as "a possible relationship between...". As you note, if you know how the force scales, you can get the power via $P=Fv$. The combination in (d) is the only one consistent with that requirement.

Answer (score 1):

What you may not know is that resistive forces are not always proportional to a body's speed. This proportionality applies when the resistive force is of viscous origin and the body is moving slowly enough for there to be streamline flow. For higher speeds, the momentum change of the fluid pushed out of the way by the moving object is a more important effect, and a square law relationship, $F=k v^2$ may be a better approximation. You can now see that a possible correct answer *is* available.

Comment: I don't think this is a very good answer.  This requires OP to somehow assume the nature of viscous drag.  This can be answered just with the information in the question ($P$ depends on $F$ and $v$, $F$ depends on $v$); without trying to guess how drag works.

Comment: I think your criticism of my answer is that (d) is the only option available consistent with P = Fv, and must therefore be selected on these grounds alone. Yes, but the questioner didn't $want$ to select(d), presumably because he didn't realise that there could be resistive forces that weren't proportional to speed.  That's why I gave the answer that I did, rather than sticking to the logical minimum as stated in my first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

F=kv^2

This is the relation between resistive force ( drag force and velocity). So use this and then you will get the correct answer i.e., D.